# How should I interpret Quran [a:b]?

Tags: quran, terminology, ayah

What is 'a' and 'b'? As in how do I interpret the various quotes that I see around?

Answer (score 2):

I think most of the time the first number indicates the number of the Surah, the second number indicates the number of the verse, i.e. Qur'an[2:3] = Surat Al-Baqarah, verse number 3.